# How to edit or delete a specific connection in TeamSQL

Tags: mysql, teamsql

I have created a MySQL connection in using the GUI tool TeamSQL. I need to edit the connection properties.

I tried to find settings tab but I am not able to find anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I followed these steps:

1. Click on the **Databases** tab
2. Under **Connections** disconnect the database connection first

   [image]
3. Once disconnected you can **Edit** or **Delete** the connection

   [image]
4. Edit the values and **Save** the connection.

   [image]